# Creating a v-simple-table table with multiple properties object

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to Vue and vuetify and I am trying to render a simple table with 2 columns. For my first column, I have no issue iterating through my `user_info` object's property `titles`, but I can't find the way to access my second property `data` for my second column.

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-left">champs</th>
                    <th class="text-left">data</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="item in user_info.titles">
                    <td> {{ item }} </td>
                    <td>data</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </template>
        </v-simple-table>
    </v-container>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                user_info: {
                    titles: [
                        'First name',
                        'Last name',
                        'Account nº',
                        'Email',
                        'Phone',
                        'City',
                        'Postal code',
                        'Region'],
                    data: [
                        'xxxx',
                        'xxxx',
                        'xxxx',
                        'xxxx',
                        'xxxx',
                        'xxxx',
                        'xxxx',
                        'xxxx',
                        'xxxx',
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Since I can't use more than 1 `v-for` in my `<tr>` tag, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can use `v-show` for the second property and use the `index` of your `v-for` rendering.

```
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(item, index) in user_info.titles">
                    <td> {{ item }} </td>
                    <td v-show="user_info.data">{{user_info.data[index]}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
```

That solves it.